# bad resolution of illustrator file in after effect

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, resolution, adobe-after-effects, import

I've created an illustrator file then import it in after effect, but when import it i got bad resolution
How can get good resolution :(
Thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please provide more information. File dimensions, workflow, etc. As it is.. all anyone can do is *guess* because there's not much information in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Your timeline resolution is most likely not set to full. This renders the video preview at less than 100% for performance purposes. If you set the timeline resolution to Full, scrubbing through the timeline may lag depending on your file and your computer hardware.

[image: resolution test]

You can read more about the resolutions options on Adobe's help page

> Auto: (available only for previews) Adapts the resolution of the view
> in the Composition panel to render only the pixels necessary to
> preview the composition at the current zoom level. For example, if the
> view is zoomed out to 25%, then the resolution automatically adapts to
> a value of 1/4—shown as (Quarter)—as if you had manually chosen
> Quarter. If a panel contains multiple views, the resolution adapts to
> the view with the highest zoom level. This setting gives the best
> image quality while also avoiding rendering pixels unnecessary for the
> current zoom level.
>
> Full: Renders each pixel in a composition. This setting gives the best
> image quality, but takes the longest to render.
>
> Half: Renders one-quarter of the pixels contained in the
> full-resolution image—half the columns and half the rows.
>
> Third: Renders one-ninth of the pixels contained in the
> full-resolution image.
>
> Quarter: Renders one-sixteenth of the pixels contained in the
> full-resolution image.
>
> Custom: Renders the image at the horizontal and vertical resolutions
> that you specify.

[Choose a view layout and share view settings](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/modifying-using-views.html#WS3878526689cb91655866c1103906c6dea-7f0ea)

Comment: Oh, Thanks!
it's right :"")

Comment: @Nada If this answers your questions, please mark as Accepted Answer. Thank you.